# Sending a file to uCLinux

Tags: linux, ethernet, file-transfer, serial-port, embedded

I have a board running uClinux, and I need to send a file to it, but I'm not sure how... I have a RS232 port, and Ethernet port with an IP address at my disposal, I can telnet to the board, but uCLinux doesn't have a built in FTP client.

What sort of options do I have here for transferring files from my Windows 7 (or OpenSUSE) machine(s) to this board?

**EDIT**

I just found I have a TFTP server on it:

```
# tftp
BusyBox v0.60.5 (2012.07.09-14:05+0000) multi-call binary

Usage: tftp [OPTION]... HOST [PORT]
```

But I can't find any good information on how to use TFTP. And looking around google I'm seeing it's good for loading binary images, so I'm assume anything could be sent, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Does it have a ssh server installed?

Comment: @m4573r - Doesn't look like it, I'm getting `ssh: not found`.

Comment: I found this [tutorial on how to install dropbear](https://docs.blackfin.uclinux.org/doku.php?id=uclinux-dist:dropbear), which is apparently a small SSH server. If you manage to get it up and running, transferring your files would be really easy...